# Adding more than 50 users to a private blog on Blogger

Tags: blogger, blog, permissions, user-accounts

I have set up a private blog in Blogger, and now I am adding users who will be able to see the blog under Settings -> Basic -> Permissions -> Blog Readers -> Add Readers. It seems that I am restricted to 50 users, and I need to add 70+ users. I am wondering if there is a limit to 50 users, and if so, if there is any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the limit is 100 invitations - ever.   It doesn't matter if those invitations are accepted or not, once they're sent, they count towards the limit.

Could it be that you've added 50 invitations before now, and so the current 50 mean you have reached the limit?     (Or maybe Blogger has changed the limit).

Also, once you have reached the limit, I don't believe that there's any way to extend this.

Comment: Thanks. I am not aware of having invited more than 50 people.  The first attempt was to invite 67 people from a gmail group, but only 50 were added. Having a limit of 100 users would be fine.

Comment: I have now reverted to the old Blogger system and I have 51 users showing up under 'Who can view this blog?' with 46 invitations below, many of which are duplicates of the email addresses in the list of 51 users.  So it would seem that, using the old system at least, I can add more than 50 users, but I am confused as to what is going on with the list of 51 users (not all of whom have accepted invitations) and the duplicates in the list of 46 invitations.  Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "the old Blogger system"?

Answer (score 0):

I personally haven't tried this one.
Try creating a Distribution List if it is a Private domain & share it with the DL.